# How to handle chrome extension panel's onSearch event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

How can I handle the `onSearch` event in my chrome devtools extension panel, which will fire when hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and typing some query string.

In my panel's background page I can listen for that event, but I don't know how to access it within the panel itself neither how to respond with the number of matches to get the search navigation working like in Elements Panel:
[image: Element Panel's Search]

This functionality is very poorly documented on this link:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels

Comment: Not much clear about your question. So what's the issue with onSearch event?

Comment: Basically, there isn't much documentation on the subject

Comment: Look at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1163519

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not clear, but still documented by the link you specified.

You can set listener when creating a dev panel:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create("My Dev Panel", null, "panel.html", function(panel) {
    panel.onSearch.addListener(function(action, querySearch) {
        // action - May be: 
        //   "performSearch", "cancelSearch", "nextSearchResult", "previousSearchResult"
        // querySearch - search text
    });
});
```

Btw, I suggest you to use debounce function for search implementation, because `onSearch` event fires on each key down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `chrome.runtime` api to pass the message to your main script.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/

```js
panel.onSearch.addListener((action, queryString) => {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: "search",
    payload: { action, queryString },
  });
});
```

Then inside your HTML page

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((event) => {
  console.log(event);
});
```